# Why the bullets have no force they are not moving forward and the rotation is also not as the fire point?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Screenshot of the bullets when firing :

[image: Bullets]

The bullets are stay still and they are standing.

This screenshot show the Fire Point inspector position rotation scaling :

[image: Fire Point]

And a screenshot of the bullet prefab settings :

[image: Bullet Prefab]

Last screenshot show the Shooting gameobject inspector settings :

[image: Shooting GameObject Inspector settings]

And the script Shooting :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Shooting : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform[] firePoints;
    [SerializeField]
    private Rigidbody projectilePrefab;
    [SerializeField]
    private float launchForce = 700f;

    public void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            LaunchProjectile();
        }
    }

    private void LaunchProjectile()
    {
        foreach (var firePoint in firePoints)
        {
            var projectileInstance = Instantiate(
                projectilePrefab,
                firePoint.position,
                firePoint.rotation);

            projectileInstance.AddForce(firePoint.forward * launchForce);
        }
    }
}
```

And how can I make that it will not leave a trail of bullets behind ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the rotation you want to set the projectile to the same rotation as the weapon.

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(gunAngle)
```

the projectile should be another gameObject instead of rigidBody.

you'll also need a destruction script on them or they'll never disappear and you will have a million projectiles in play lagging the game. destroy gameObject by collision and time.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the trail of bullets, you should consider adding a cooldown to the LaunchProjectile method. Right now every time update is called it calls LaunchProjectile if the fire button is down, even if it called LaunchProjectile the update before (at 60 ups(?) you'd have to be pretty fast off of the fire button to only shoot one projectile).